# TwoSums code only returning [0,0]

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, return

I'm practicing coding questions and i'm not sure why my code isn't working (i know it's not written very efficiently:/ )

given an array and a target number, return the indices of two numbers in the array that add up to the target number. Example: nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]. (indices have to be diff)

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] <= target)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(nums[i]); 
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                {
                    return new int[]{i, j};
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return new int[]{0,0};
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do the indices have to be different? For a target of 14 could you return [1, 1]?

Comment: yes, the indices have to be different

Comment: In that case you can change the second loop to start at `j = i + 1`. As for your problem I can't see any issues with the code so could you post your usage? I.e. how you're calling the function.

Comment: I'm using leetcode to run the code so i'm not calling the function - modifying it to j = i +1 seemed to fix it! At least my output now matches theirs - thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, if the two numbers must be different, you have to start iterate over `j` in `i + 1`.

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] <= target)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                {
                    return new int[]{i, j};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[]{0,0};
}
```